# Android - make selected tab bold

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have ActionBar with NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS and some amount of actual tabs in my application. The task is quite simple: make selected tab title bold (and returning to normal when tab loses selection). But it became a big headache to achieve such a task. Tab object has no methods for accessing underlying TextView. So I've used custom view for tab title, but then this view is positioned wrong:

[image: titles are sticked to the top]

Please help and tell me:

- if there's a way to manipulate tab text directly, or
- how can I achieve default positioning for custom TextView?

The code I'm using:

in Activity ->

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            TextView textView = (TextView) tab.getCustomView();
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) tab.getCustomView();
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)
                getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_title, null);
        textView.setText("Tab " + i);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setCustomView(textView)
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
```

in layout.tab_title ->

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the ActionBar.Tab has a `setText(CharSequence)` you can do something like the follow in the `onTabSelected`/`onTabUnselected` callback:

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(String.valueOf(tab.getText()));        
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(TypeFace.BOLD), 0, wordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tab.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

You might need to use a different Spannable,SPAN_X_X constant though

Edit: Made more generic for use in the callback (take text already present in the tab).

Comment: My apologies then; I haven't tried coding this myself. Most Android UI elements that accept CharSequence honor Spans. I did a quick look through the source code for ActionBar Tabs and it appears that it just passes the text strait through to a TextView. For you custom view implementation, you should try adding 'android:gravity="center"' to your tab_title.xml and setting the LayoutParams to be MATCH_PARENT for width and height.